# Getting new UNIX Timestamp on every update in ng-bind(HTML view)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in an Angular project, I have a `div` like this:

```
<div ng-bind="getDate()"></div>
```

and `$scope.getDate` function inside `Controller`:

```
$scope.getDate = function () {
        return Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);
};
```

What i want is every time that `$scope.getDate` updates, My HTML view get's update too. but it doesn't happens. `$scope.getDate` return UNIX Timestamp and every millisecond updates, but HTML view not. how can achieve something like that?

Comment: How do you want to trigger `$scope.getDate()`?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, update triggered by a button:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.getDate = function () {
        $scope.date = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="getDate()">Update!</button>
    {{date}}
</div>
```